# Why is the data not sent over a raw socket in windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I have python code that sends self-built udp packets over a raw socket. This works on Linux (Ubuntu) but not on Windows (10).

The socket is opened like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import ipaddress
import socket
import struct
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)

    message = "myMessage"
    addr = ("127.0.0.1", 2001)

    message_encoded = message.encode()
    udp_msg = struct.pack("!HHHH"+str(len(message_encoded))+"s",
                          2002, addr[1], 8 + len(message_encoded),
                          0, message_encoded)
    ip_header = struct.pack("!BBHHHBBHLL",
                            4*16 + 5,
                            0,
                            20 + len(udp_msg),
                            12345,
                            0x0000,
                            255,
                            socket.IPPROTO_UDP,
                            0,
                            int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(addr[0])),
                            int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(addr[0])))
    data = ip_header + udp_msg
    print(data.hex())
    output_len = sender.sendto(data, addr)
    print("Sent message to {}: {} ({} bytes, total {} bytes).".format(addr, message,
                len(message_encoded), output_len))
```

When I run this script on linux (with sudo) the message is sent to the listening server, but when I run it on windows (with administrative privileges) the message never reaches the server.

Comment: run it on linux (with administrative privileges) - did you mean Windows here?

Comment: @11_22_33 yes, thank you, it is changed now

Answer (score 0):

Using raw sockets on M$ Windows 10 is prohibited.
Winpcap and its successor npcap is a solution.

Comment: Do you have an example how to use npcap in a python script?